# Работа с файлами на веб сайтах

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть сайт WooCommerce(Wordpress). Я хочу туда добавить"Virtual Product", который берет файл и, например, меняет фон или что-то делает, как в фотошопе, или же делает изображение векторным и т.д...
Как сделать, создать такую систему, которaя работает как в фотошопе?

Comment: Сам-то понял что спросил?

Comment: Азербайджанец,русский хромает. Хочу как remove.bg

Comment: https://www.remove.bg/api и писать плагин. За основу можно взять https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-remove-bg/. Или  что-то подобное использовать https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-paint/